# generate number series for new entries based on existing data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have existing data like

```
+-------+-----+----------+
| House | Pet | ItemCode |
+-------+-----+----------+
| A     | Cat | ACat001  |
| A     | Dog | ADog001  |
| B     | Cat | BCat001  |
| A     | Dog | ADog002  |
+-------+-----+----------+
```

I want to generate new item codes for new entries by T-SQL like

```
+-------+-----+----------+--------------------------------+
| House | Pet | ItemCode | ItemCodes supposed to generate |
+-------+-----+----------+--------------------------------+
| A     | Cat | ????     | ACat002                        |
| C     | Dog | ????     | CDog001                        |
+-------+-----+----------+--------------------------------+
```

Please help.

Comment: what is the logic on this result?

Comment: who voted this question up, at lease can you please let us know the expecting logic require for this output!!

Comment: The user wants to build the a logic to generate new item code for newly inserted data based on house and pet. so a newly inserted cat in house A will have a ACat002 itemcode as a cat in house A already exists.

Comment: sorry guys. yes the logic is like @ughai said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to keep another column as a `Index` so as to break item code in `House`,`Pet` and `Index` and create the `itemcode` from these and also have an identity column as a primary key in the table which would make the solution simpler and better in performance.

Considering the table as is, you can first get the max index for each pet in a house and then use it to calculate the next index and update the `itemcode` for the newly inserted data.

**Table Scripts and Inserts**

```
CREATE TABLE HousePet
    ([House] varchar(1), [Pet] varchar(3), [ItemCode] varchar(7));

INSERT INTO HousePet
    ([House], [Pet], [ItemCode])
VALUES
    ('A', 'Cat', 'ACat001'),
    ('A', 'Dog', 'ADog001'),
    ('B', 'Cat', 'BCat001'),
    ('A', 'Dog', 'ADog002');

-- new rows inserted for which `ItemCode` is required
INSERT INTO HousePet
    ([House], [Pet], [ItemCode])
    VALUES
    ('A', 'Cat', NULL),
    ('C', 'Dog', NULL);
```

**Update SQL**

```
;WITH HousePetIndex AS
(
    SELECT House,Pet,MAX(CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(ItemCode,House + Pet,''))) as MaxIndex
    FROM HousePet
    WHERE ItemCode IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY House,Pet
), HousePetInserted as 
(
    SELECT HP.House,HP.Pet,HP.ItemCode,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY HP.House,HP.Pet ORDER BY HP.House) as ItemIndex
    FROM HousePet HP
    WHERE ItemCode IS NULL
)
UPDATE HP1
SET ItemCode = HP1.House + HP1.Pet + RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),ItemIndex + ISNULL(HP2.MaxIndex,0)),3)
FROM HousePetInserted HP1
LEFT JOIN HousePetIndex HP2
    ON HP1.House = HP2.House AND HP1.Pet = HP2.Pet

SELECT * FROM HousePet
```

**Logic**

- Get max index for existing data per house and pet in `HousePetIndex` CTE
- Identify new rows with some index based on `row_number` in case multiple rows for same pet and house are inserted
- Update the `itemcode` for new rows based on `House`,`Pet` and `Index` derived from max index and index or new rows

**OUTPUT**

```
House   Pet ItemCode
A   Cat ACat001
A   Dog ADog001
B   Cat BCat001
A   Dog ADog002
A   Cat ACat002
C   Dog CDog001
```

---

**EDIT**

If you do decide to add an `itemindex` and an identity column `ID`, you can make `ItemCode` as a computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE HousePet
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [House] varchar(1),
    [Pet] varchar(3),
    [ItemIndex] INT,
    [ItemCode] AS (House + Pet + RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),ItemIndex),3))
);
```

you can do something like this

```
UPDATE T
SET ItemIndex = rn + MaxIndex
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,House,Pet,ItemIndex,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY House,Pet ORDER BY ID ASC) rn
    FROM HousePet
    WHERE ItemIndex IS NULL
)T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT House,Pet,ISNULL(MAX(ItemIndex),0) as MaxIndex
    FROM HousePet
    GROUP BY House,Pet
) MaxIndexTable
ON MaxIndexTable.House = T.House AND MaxIndexTable.Pet = T.Pet
```

Comment: Thanks to the solution. So, the new table should be 4 columns House, Pet, Index and ItemCode(PrimaryKey), right?

Comment: Your primary key should be a separate `ID` column preferably an `IDENTITY` columns. if you do go into creating a table like this, your `ItemCode` column can then just be a computed column based on  `House`, `Pet`, `Index` and you just need to `update` the `index` in that case.

Comment: I get it. Thank you.